# Is the accelerating field removed when using the GR equivalence principle?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, equivalence-principle

Suppose I have a charged hollow sphere that is hyperbolically accelerated by a constant electric field E. The [Equivalence Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_principle#:%7E:text=In%20the%20theory%20of%20general,experienced%20by%20an%20observer%20in) tells me that this is physically equivalent to placing the charged sphere in a constant gravitational field. However, I'm unsure what happens to the accelerating electric field: is it kept as it is, or set to zero?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/459316/123208